# C++ Passing an array directly into a function without initializing it first

Tags: c++, arrays

Lets say you have created this function:

```
void function(int array1[2], int array2[2])
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this in C++

```
function([1,2],[3,4]);
```

Or maybe this can better described as

```
function({1,2},{3,4});
```

The only way I know of accomplishing this is to do:

```
int a[2] = {1,2};
int b[2] = {3,4};
function(a,b);
```

Comment: Have you compiled the first approach ?

Comment: Ya, it didn't compile.

Comment: Going forward, please test it before posting it here. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I did test it before coming here. If its supposed to work, maybe my error is for another reason.

Comment: Note that in C++ and C, your function is adjusted to `void function(int* array1, int* array2)`.

Answer (score 7):

In c++11 you could do it this way:

```
void function(std::array<int, 2> param1, std::array<int, 2> param2)
{

}
```

call it as

```
function({1,2}, {3,4});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `std::array` for some reason, in C++11 you can pass the arrays by const reference:

```
// You can do this in C++98 as well
void function(const int (&array1)[2], const int (&array2)[2]) {
}

int main() {
    // but not this
    function({1, 2}, {3, 4});
}
```

For readability `function` can be rewritten as:

```
typedef int IntArray[2];
// or using IntArray = int[2];

void function(const IntArray& array1, const IntArray& array2) {
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when programming an Arduino as it doesn't have the std library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the example you gave will work either for Moustache's answer.

`function`in c++ only takes exactly the type you give to it. So if you define a function like this below:

```
void function(int array1[2], int array2[2])
{
    // Do Something
}
```

You specify that the arguments must an pointer of int. When you write like `[2,3]` or `{2,3}`, they are not actually any type. The reason that we could write like int `a[2] = {2,3}` because in c++, there are constructors for `=` operation of each type. This constructor takes `{2,3}` as parameter to construct an array and give it to the variable before `=` operand.

So the problem here is that the `=` operation doesn't return anything, so it is not acceptable to the function if you give it an argument: `int a = 0`, this won't return `a` to the function.

But here is some other interesting function that does return something, so they can be used as a parameter.

```
void somefunction(int a) {
    printf("This is the argument: %d!\n" a);
}
int main() {
    somefunction(printf("Guess if I could compile and run!\n"));
    return 0
}
```

This is a very simple example here. You could try to run this by yourself, if I type this right(I didn't compile in the compiler with this code but similar code), this should print out two lines:

```
Guess if I could compile and run!
This is the argument: (somenumber)!
```

This is because that function `printf` always returns the number of characters it printed, although we don't care about it in most case. So here as long as the `thing` (could be anything, function or variables) gives the function the same type of argument, the function will accept it, otherwise, it won't let you pass the compile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "You specify that the arguments must be array of two ints". No, you specify the parameters are pointers to `int`. C++ is funny that way (thanks to C.) See my comment to the question.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I will corrected that part of my answer.

Answer (score -3):

It has been awhile since I have done C++ but if I remember correctly, you can specify default values for the parameters if none are passed into the function. I would imagine you could do the same thing for an array value instead of an int.  See the example below.

```
function(int a = 1, int b = 2);
function(int a [5] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071}, int b[1] = {2});
```